# Add up total of array values multiplied by input value in react component

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, cumulative-sum

I have a react component pulled in from a JSON array which includes an input that a allows a user to select the quantity of a product. My current issue is that I need a way to multiply all of the product prices by their quantity and output them into a total. I've managed to achieve this for each component but I really need a running total that updates when the quantity is changed. The difficulty here is that some values in the array will not be included as they may not be classed as a peripheral.

Being fairly new to react I'm hoping that someone can suggest a solution. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

My code as it stands is below

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import productdata from "./catalog.json";
    import productSort from "./OrderDetails";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          BundleVal: "",
          ProductCounter: [],
          TotalCounter: [],
          PeripheralCounter: 0,
          PriceCounter: 0 

        };
      }

      updateBundle = val => {
        this.setState({
          BundleVal: val
        });
      };

      updateQuantity = e => {
        var pCounter = this.state.ProductCounter;
        var el = parseInt(e.target.id.split("_")[1], 10);
        pCounter[el] = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
        this.setState({ ProductCounter: pCounter });
      };

      render() {
        const BundleProducts = [].concat(productSort).map((item, i) =>
          <div key={item.id}>
            {item.id} <br />
            {item.name} <br />
            {item.description} <br />
            Installation: {item.price.installation} <br />
            Monthly: {item.price.recurring} <br />
            <input
              type="number"
              onChange={this.updateQuantity}
              value={this.state.ProductCounter[item.id] || 0}
              id={"product_" + item.id}
            />
            <br />
            {this.state.ProductCounter[item.id] || 0}<br />

            Installation Total: £{parseFloat(this.state.ProductCounter[item.id] * item.price.installation, 10).toFixed(2)}
            <br />
            Monthly Total: £{parseFloat(this.state.ProductCounter[item.id] * item.price.recurring, 10).toFixed(2)}
            <br />
            <hr />
          </div>
        );



        this.state.PeripheralCounter = this.state.ProductCounter
          .filter(function(qty, pid) {
            pid = String(pid);
            for (var i = 0; i < productSort.length; i++) {
              var p = productSort[i];
              if (p.isPeripheral === true && p.id === pid) {
                return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          })
          .reduce(function(count, carry) {
            return count + carry;
          }, 0);




        let bname = null;
        let maxperipherals = null;
        if (this.state.BundleVal === "1") {
          bname = productdata.data.bundles[0].name;
          maxperipherals = productdata.data.bundles[0].maximumPeripherals;
        } else if (this.state.BundleVal === "2") {
          bname = productdata.data.bundles[1].name;
          maxperipherals = productdata.data.bundles[1].maximumPeripherals;
        } else if (this.state.BundleVal === "3") {
          bname = productdata.data.bundles[2].name;
          maxperipherals = productdata.data.bundles[2].maximumPeripherals;
        } else if (this.state.BundleVal === "4") {
          bname = productdata.data.bundles[3].name;
          maxperipherals = productdata.data.bundles[3].maximumPeripherals;
        } else {
          bname = null;
        }

        return (
          <div>
            <h2>Order</h2>
            Chosen Bundle: {bname}
            <br />
            Number of Peripherals: {this.state.PeripheralCounter}
            <br />
            Maximum Number of Peripherals: {maxperipherals}
            <br />
            Peripherals Installation Total: {}
            <br />
            <Bundle updateBundle={this.updateBundle} />
            <h3>Products</h3>
            {BundleProducts}

          </div>
        );
      }
    }



    class Bundle extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          BundleVal: ""
        };
      }

      updatebundle = e => {
        this.props.updateBundle(e.target.value);
        this.setState({ BundleVal: e.target.value });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h4>Bundle</h4>
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="1"
              onChange={this.updatebundle}
              checked={this.state.BundleVal === "1"}
            />
            {" "}Indoor Camera RAPID
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="2"
              onChange={this.updatebundle}
              checked={this.state.BundleVal === "2"}
            />
            {" "}Alarm Only RAPID
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="3"
              onChange={this.updatebundle}
              checked={this.state.BundleVal === "3"}
            />
            {" "}Outdoor Camera RAPID
            <input
              type="radio"
              value="4"
              onChange={this.updatebundle}
              checked={this.state.BundleVal === "4"}
            />
            {" "}Build Your Own Bundle
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    class Product extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          ProductVal: ""
        };
      }

      updateproduct = e => {
        this.props.updateProduct(e.target.value);
        this.setState({ ProductVal: e.target.value });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h4>Product</h4>
            <br />
            <input type="number" onChange={this.updateproduct} />

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    export default App;
```

This code also pulls in a formula from a separate component

```
var productSort = productdata.data.products;

productSort.sort(function(a, b){return a.id - b.id});
```

An example of my Json values are as follows

```
{
    "timestamp": 1502121471,
    "data": {
        "adverts": [],
        "bundles": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Bundle 1",
            "description": "Bundle 1 Description",
            "maximumPeripherals": 32,
            "available": true,
            "count": 0,  
            "price": {
                "installation": "99.99",
                "recurring": "23.99"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "bundle-one.png",
            },
            "products": ["1", "2", "3"]
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Bundle 2",
            "description": "Bundle 2 Description",
            "maximumPeripherals": 32,
            "available": true,
            "count": 0,  
            "price": {
                "installation": "99.99",
                "recurring": "23.99"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "bundle-two.png",

            },
            "products": ["1", "2", "2", "2", "2"]
        }],
        "products": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "description": "Product 1 Description",
            "maximumQuantity": 1,
            "isPeripheral": false,
            "isAvailable": true,
            "price": {
                "upfront": null,
                "installation": "0.00",
                "recurring": "0.00"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "product-one.png",
            }
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Product 2",
            "description": "Product 2 Description",
            "maximumQuantity": null,
            "isPeripheral": true,
            "isAvailable": true,
            "count": 0,  
            "price": {
                "upfront": "60.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "1.25"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "product-two.png",
            }
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Product Three",
            "description": "Product Three Description",
            "maximumQuantity": null,
            "isPeripheral": true,
            "isAvailable": true,
            "count": 0,  
            "price": {
                "upfront": "132.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "2.75"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "product-three.png",
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a bit of figuring but I have an answer. Essentially it's a for loop which iterates over the array created by BundleProducts and multiplies the children inside the props which include the installation cost and quantity input (in this case 10 and 19 respectively). If anyone has a better solution please feel free to post it.

```
var myTotal = 0; 
  for(var i = 0, len = BundleProducts.length; i < len; i++) {
    myTotal += BundleProducts[i].props.children[19] * BundleProducts[i].props.children[10];  
}
```